# Image to grayscale with different methods in Java OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv

I have a problem to convert color image to grayscale image using another method than:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(colorPhoto, grayscalePhoto, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

I tried this:

```
Core.inRange(colorPhoto, new Scalar(0, 0, 0), new Scalar(200, 200, 200), grayscalePhoto);
```

but it's giving me only black and white colors.

I know there's also method with histogram but I don't know how to do it exactly. Can I get grayscale image from inRange method or I have to do sth else?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found an easy solution.
When you're reading image using `Imgcodecs` method:

```
Imgcodecs.imread(image,0)
```